# How do I configure task scheduler so it runs a vbscript when I open another program?

Tags: excel, vbscript

I'm trying to attach a vbscript onto my windows scheduler so that as soon as I open a program (for example, Google Chrome) it runs an excel macro in the background.  I've looked into task scheduler and can't find the ability to trigger events based on opening another program, as opposed to an administrative message or error.  Sorry for the noob question!

Comment: Easiest hack - Why not create a `.bat` file that has (1) the program to run first, (2) the other program (Chrome) and then just run / put in your start menu, etc. the shortcut for that file rather than Chrome?

Comment: Hey Bustos - thanks - that's a good workaround but I guess what I will need is for different scripts to run based on different instances of the program.  For example if I'm running Adobe Acrobat, I'd like the opening of one pdf to trigger one vbscript, and another pdf to trigger an alternate one.

Comment: Turn on auditing, set chromre to be audited. Then it will appear as events in security log in Event Viewer.

Comment: Maybe task scheduler can run a script (based on something like [this](http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/adminscripts/monitoring/processes/#ProcessCreation.htm)) which always runs in the background. When a new process of interest is created, the script could then run another script (or it could all be part of the same script) which performs whatever actions you want for that application.

Answer (score 0):

This is from Windows SDK WMI section. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392396(v=vs.85).aspx

This monitors 6 (i=0 to 5) program starts and exits.

```
strComputer = "." 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" _
    & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2") 
Set objEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery _
    ("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessTrace")

Wscript.Echo "Waiting for events ..."
i = 0
Do Until i=5
    Set objReceivedEvent = objEvents.NextEvent
    'report an event
    Wscript.Echo "Win32_ProcessTrace event occurred" & VBNewLine _
        & "Process Name = " _
            & objReceivedEvent.ProcessName & VBNewLine _
        & "Process ID = " _
            & objReceivedEvent.Processid & VBNewLine _
        & "Session ID = " & objReceivedEvent.SessionID 
i = i+ 1
Loop
```